# Best approach to get current url from razor view with HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor view with a canonical meta tag with the current url as a parameter, but this url has to be `https`, so I'm doing something like this:

```
string secureUrl = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://") : string.Empty;

<link rel="canonical" href="@secureUrl" />
```

Is this the best way to get the `https` version of the url?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `@Url.Action()` method's fourth parameter to change protocol and pass other parameters null to get current url with https like following.

```
@{
   string secureUrl = Url.Action(null, null, null, "https"); // current url with https
}

<link rel="canonical" href="@secureUrl" />
```